# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

i had created card component and i called in my ProductPage.js after that i am getting error like  Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/media/Card.c3b0a67ff849f2bda062.JS') is not a valid name.
initially it was div and i change to card after that i am getting above error if changed div then it is working fine how can i solve this issue.
For ref Please find the attached image.
[image]

[image]

and code is like this.

ProductPage.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getProductPage } from "../redux/actions";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import getParams from "../utils/getParams";
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"; // requires a loader
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
import Card from "../Components/Card.JS";

function ProductPage() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const product = useSelector((state) => state.product);
  const { page } = product;
  const { search } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = getParams(search);
    console.log(params);
    const payload = {
      params,
    };
    dispatch(getProductPage(payload));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "0 10px" }}>
      {page.title}
      <Carousel renderThumbs={() => {}}>
        {page.banners &&
          page.banners.map((banner, index) => (
            <a
              key={index}
              style={{ display: "block" }}
              href={banner.navigateTo}
            >
              <img src={banner.img} alt="" />
            </a>
          ))}
      </Carousel>
      <div>
        {page.products &&
          page.products.map((product, index) => (
            <Card key={index}>
              <img src={product.img} alt="" />
            </Card>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductPage;
```

Card.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

function Card(props) {
  return <div className="card">{props.card}</div>;
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the img tag inside the card so you need to render the children not the props.card.

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

function Card(props) {
  return <div className="card">{props.children}</div>;
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: not working getting same error

Comment: img url is correct?    <img src={product.img} alt="" />

Comment: Yes image url Correct

Comment: Paste complete console screenshot.

Comment: Done please check

Comment: initially it was div and i change to card after that i am getting above error. you are talking about Card Component right ?

Comment: Yes Deepk i am talking about card only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240537/discussion-between-deepak-and-somutesting).